# categories image was not showing in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Hi i was used this code to display categories with corresponding image. I am using prestashop 1.4.4

```
<ul>            
{foreach from=$blockCategTree.children item=child name=blockCategTree}
{if $smarty.foreach.blockCategTree.last}
{include file="$branche_tpl_path" node=$child last='true'}
{else}
{include file="$branche_tpl_path" node=$child}
{/if}
<img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($category->link_rewrite, $category->id_image, 'category')}" alt="{$category->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$category->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" id="categoryImage" />          
{/foreach}      
</ul>
```

By seeing the src attribute using firebug, it shows the path like this-
/prestashop/img/c/-category.jpg

and i want like this to display image- "/prestashop/img/c/6-category.jpg"
here 6 is image id. How can i usethe code to get url like above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need

```
<img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($subcategory.link_rewrite, $subcategory.id_category,'category_default')|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="" width="{$mediumSize.width}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi May be this can help you

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category, $subcategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$subcategory.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="img">
```